# Run Java program from Eclipse Builders

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a Java program as a builder before the Java Builder kicks in. The Java class to be run is part of another project within the workspace.

I can add Program builder but I don't want to point explicitly to a Java VM as my teammates may have their Java installed in different location. Is there a way to achieve this without referring to a particular JVM executable?

EDIT: Added screenshot of Eclipse Builders to show which config I'm talking about. [image: Screenshot of Eclipse Builders configuration]

Comment: How are you specifying this builder?

Comment: @greg-449 Check out the screenshot I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can run the java program using a normal launcher (.launch file created using Run/Debug Configuration). I figured out a way to make that work as a Builder step.

Simply move the `.launch` to `.externalToolBuilders` and modify the `.project` file in a text editor to pick up that `.launch` file.

```
<buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
    <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
    <arguments>
    <dictionary>
        <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
        <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/MyCustomJavaProgram.launch</value>
    </dictionary>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Eclipse being the good boy it is, doesn't complain about the presence of a `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication` as a Builder step and everything works smoothly. In fact if you edit this newly added Builder step it even shows the correct Edit launch configuration dialog.

Comment: But manually adding a launch configuration file (`.launch`) to `.externalToolBuilders` is exactly the same as creating a *Program Builder* with the *Builders* dialog, isn't it? Why do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a builder in Java is to create a plugin and use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point. Your builder class then extends the `org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder` class and has access to lots of detail about what is being built.

This method does not require a JVM to be specified anywhere as your plugin runs as part of Eclipse.

Comment: while that may be useful in general, in my case it's a bit of an overkill. i don't want to force a plugin installation on part of other team members either.